# How to know the path of the MSI or EXE from which a software program was installed

Tags: installer, windows-installer

There have been times when I have forgotten the MSI or EXE I installed a software from and I need the file path of the installer to use it elsewhere. Is it possible to know the MSI or EXE from which a software program was installed?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to look under:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

or

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products (look under a GUID for the SourceList items)

The 64-bit path will be slightly different. I don't have the exact one since I run this old clunker PC at the moment.

**IMPORTANT**: Do not under any circumstance delete anything from HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products! It is the Windows Installer database - it is very fragile if tampered with.

Comment: Thanks! The second path has more useful information. LastUserSource property shows the folder location of the MSI while PackageName provides the name of the MSI. In the first path that you specified, there is a property called InstallSource available only for some programs. Is that supposed to be the location of the executable from which a program was installed?

Comment: Yes, I believe so - this first location is used by the Add/Remove Programs applet run from control panel.

Comment: This method seems to track only MSIs. Anyway to locate EXEs?